# How To Make List Of Fragments In Android Programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android application and one of the features is a list of upcoming events. I need to be able to generate a 'card' so to speak for each of these events and place them in to a scroll view. This would be simple if I knew how many there were going to be and could prepopulate an axml file but I must populate the scrollview programmatically based off the parse of an xml file on the web so that the client can keep it updated. I've searched everything I can think and the best I can find is a custom list view which I do not think will provide the results needed. I've uploaded an example of what I'm trying to do to my google drive and linked to it below. I should also mention my background is completely C# and I've only been working with java for the last two weeks or so, so if anyone could provide a working code example I would be most appreciative.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8alYNlu3SuoSEk0bE55cDhXWVE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that basically what you need to do is to implement a RecyclerView using a LinearLayoutManager (this would represent basically a list) with CardViews as the items or just regular layouts designed by you, the CardView will just make your life easier if you need the Material Design cards appearance.

You have many different tutorials as how to implement this, as you can see here:
http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

You'll see there that it's exactly what you need but with smaller Cards.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need. Thanks again, Brother.